# Using Distinct in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

How to display all fields of a row based on 1 field that is distinct (i.e there should no duplicates for this field)

Suppose there's a table called Office_Roles with the fields and data as below

```
Name   Department   Designation

John   Marketing    Executive
John   Sales        Executive
John   PR           Executive
```

So i want the end result to display all the fields in a row but for just 1 John (distinct)

Output like -

John Marketing(or Sales) (or Pr)  Executive

I was thinking of something like

```
select * from Office_Roles where name =(select distinct name from Office_Roles);
```

How do we do something like this correctly ?  I also want to do a Order By and Limit the number of results per page on the end result...

Comment: Are you looking to do a `JOIN` or use `EXISTS`?

Comment: there are three departments for user `John`, what do you want to display then?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I would be using a left outer join in origional query which I think does not affect the output for what I'm asking this question...

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: You just want to pick a random row for John in your example? Show your sample output and it will be clearer what you want. You say you want the "first" row, but what defines the first row?

Comment: @JW - Any department could be displayed for John (John here is the same person who full fills 3 different office roles)

Comment: @JohnFx - Exactly - any random row...

Comment: This gets asked a lot here try this link to see some of the other answers to very similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Comment: Question edited  for what should be the output type... See above

Comment: The query to get the roles in 3 different roles in one row is possible using `group_concat()` like Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable number of columns for a query.  One thing you can do is to concatenate the values together:

```
select name, group_concat(Department) as departments,
       group_concat(Designation) as designations
from Office_Roles o
group by name
```

Comment: how about `group_concat(DISTINCT Designation)`? `:D`

Comment: @JW . . . I don't actually know.  This is an educated guess about what might help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I don't need group_concat()... Please see my comments below for dougis and medina's  answers...

Comment: I think you do need group concat since you stressed that you just want one row.

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't understand Distinct correctly... How do i get the subquery to return only 1 of the john's and then based on the subquery's result, the outer query fetches the rest of the fields ...

Comment: @user481913 . . . The subquery only returns one "John" because of the `group by`.  I would suggest that you focus on learning `group by` instead of `distinct`.  The use of `select distinct` is syntactic short-hand for a `group by`, and the latter is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get 3 rows either way since there are 3 in the table that match, which rows are you trying to exclude and how is the query supposed to know what to NOT show?

Comment: well doesn't the distinct clause in the subquery return me only 1 John out of 3 and then based on this John the outer query fetches me the rest of the fields in the row?

Comment: then you must create an Id field which increments dynamically when the records are added and you can compare with id to get the required result.

Comment: No, the subquery will give you 1 John which will then match all 3 rows in the outer query.  

You are getting 3 rows regardless. Which rows do you want excluded from the table result set.

To test replace the subquery with name="John" and see what you get (that is a single result), if you don't have the distinct in the subquery you would actually get 9 rows 3 each at the main query for each of the 3 Johns in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This will not output exactly how you want , but see if it works for you. Just to give you an idea.

```
select name, group_concat(Department SEPARATOR ' or ') as departments,
       Designation
from Office_Roles  a
group by name,Designation
```

Yoy can play with SQL Fiddle here [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bebe/2)

Answer (score -1):

I would just use GROUP BY

```
SELECT * FROM Office_Roles GROUP BY name;
```

easy.

Comment: I did try this before - I read somewhere that in mysql when not using aggregate functions in a Group By clause ,this is similar to using Distinct...  But the client i'm working for changed something/uploaded more data probably and it doesn't seem to work.. So i thought it was better to use the sure shot way (Distinct) instead...

Comment: Hey mate.. I'm a 100% sure this query works. And also doesn't matter the size of your database. Please post here the error and the version of your mysql server and then I might be able to give you a more accurating answer.